# Why is the lm() function not working for me?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am attempting to run a multiple regression on different columns in a data frame. As it is a homework project, the main point is to show some things have less or no correlation than others.

That said, I created the data frame as follows:

```r
df.Part3 <- df %>%
  filter(NEIGHBORHOOD_NAME=="BRONXDALE",YEAR>2008,SALE_PRICE>0,TYPE=="RESIDENTIAL") %>%
  mutate(TOTAL_UNITS=RESIDENTIAL_UNITS+COMMERCIAL_UNITS) %>%
  mutate(SALE_YEAR=year(SALE_DATE)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(SALE_PRICE,SALE_YEAR,YEAR_BUILT,GROSS_SQUARE_FEET,TOTAL_UNITS,TYPE)
```

Once I do that, the data frame is created with no errors, however once I try to run the `lm()` function as follows:

```r
z <- lm(formula=SALE_PRICE~.,data=df.Part3)
```

I get the error:

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

That said, I am following the lecture video and doing almost everything alike to what the teacher is doing, however he is able to complete his and I am unable to complete mine.
How do I fix this issue?

For context surrounding the data frame:

```
SALE_PRICE:        num    260000
SALE_YEAR:         num    2009
YEAR_BUILT:        num    1965
GROSS_SQUARE_FEET: num    1152
TOTAL_UNITS:       num    1
TYPE:              chr    "RESIDENTIAL"
```

Comment: can you please share a part of your dataset, or make a mock one for this discussion? It would help out.  You can share your dataset by using the function ```dput(df)```where ```df```would be your dataframe.  Then just copy and paste the information in your question

Im guessing it's probably the structure of the data.  Check ```str(df)```and make sure things that are numerical are considered as such, and things that are categories are considered ```as.factor()```

Comment: You're filtering your data so that it only includes `TYPE == "RESIDENTIAL"` then using `TYPE` as a predictor in your model, hence the error.

Comment: I was able to run the function once I dropped the TYPE filter. Thank you.